# how to import data from 2 tables to a datagrid(joined tables with foreign key)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, join, datagrid

[image: my tables]

I have 2 classes for my 2 Tables(User_Tbl.cs and RegFee_Tbl.cs),and my classes connected together with foreign key(above picture),here is(below pictures) my property of my RegFee_Tbl.sc and my User_Tbl.cs
[image: User_Tbl.cs]

[image: RegFee_Tbl.cs]

---

and there is my datagrid(memebersDatagride is name of datagrid),I Bound 3 column of this datagrid for import data from RegFee_Tbl.cs and i bound 1 column of this datagrid to import data from User_Tbl.cs.and in my mainWindows.cs i use this method to load item from database to my datagrid,but i dont know how to import data from 2 different tables(tables connected together with FK) to a datagrid
that's my method for load item from my tables(MainWindows.cs):

```
public partial class Dashboard : UserControl
    {
        GymDbEntities db = new GymDbEntities();
        public static DataGrid datagrid;
        public Dashboard()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        Load();

    }

    private void Load()
    {

        membersdataGrid.ItemsSource = db.User_Tbl.ToList();
        //membersdataGrid.ItemsSource = db.RegFee_Tbl.ToList();
        datagrid = membersdataGrid;
    }
```

and there is my datagrid in xaml:

```
<DataGrid Language="fa-IR" x:Name="membersdataGrid" RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--bara eyjad sotone checkbox-->
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserResize="False" Width="auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="اعضا" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border Width="25" Height="25" CornerRadius="50" Margin="0 0 10 0" Background="{Binding BgColor}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Character}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="0 0 0 1"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="نام پدر" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Fee}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="شماره تماس" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding NumberPhone}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="آخرین واریزی" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FatherName}" />


                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="عملیات" IsReadOnly="True" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button  x:Name="GridEditBtn" Style="{StaticResource gridEditbutton}">
                                        <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="PencilBoxOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="GridRemoveBtn" Click="GridRemoveBtn_Click" Style="{StaticResource gridRemovebutton}" Margin="5 0 0 0" >
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="DeleteOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}" />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Entity.  So you have a Context (db) and each table is a list object.  See code below.

> 

```
GymDbEntities db = new GymDbEntities();

var results = (from u in db.User_Tbl
   join r in db.RegFee_Tbl on u.NavigationProperties equal r.NavigationProperties
   join s in sysdiagram on u.NavigationProperties equals s.NavigationProperties
   select new { u = u, r = r, s = s}
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: thankyou bro,i did that and that's worked,but when i wanna get id from my datagrid,i can't cause i joined them,
`int id = (membersdataGrid.SelectedItem as RegFee_Tbl).ID;` i can't reach ID, :( can u give me help :)

Comment: results.u.ID or results.r.ID

Comment: i got this error ("mylist"is a variable but is used like a type)
that's my code :
`List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
mylist = results.Select(l => l.ID).ToList();
            int id = (membersdataGrid.SelectedItem as mylist).ID;`

Comment: The results and the DataGrid has same index numbers.  You can get info from either.  Not sure if SelectItem is the entire row or just one cell.  So you can first get selected row number and then get data.  int rowIndex = membersdataGrid.SelectedItem.Row